Button text won't update to 'Finish' when i get to the last question for my VUE 3 quiz app
Building a quiz app in vue 3 and everything works as its suppose to til i get to the last question, where the button text is suppose to say 'Finish' as soon as the question is loaded. new to vue and been looking into this for hours even copilot cant find an error. how do i get the button text to update once the last question has been reached?
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const questions = ref([
  {
    question: 'How many books are in the kjva bible?',
    answer: 0,
    options: [
      '80',
      '32',
      '60',
    ],
    selected: null
  },
  {
    question: "What is the name of Israel's first king?",
    answer: 2,
    options: [
      'David',
      'Asa',
      'Saul',
    ],
    selected: null
  },
  {
    question: 'Salvation is of the...?',
    answer: 1,
    options: [
      'Egyptians',
      'Jews',
      'Edomites',
    ],
    selected: null
  }
])

const quizCompleted = ref(false)
const currentQuestion = ref(0)
const score = computed(() => {
  let value = 0
  questions.value.map(q => {
    if(q.selected == q.answer) {
      value++
    }
  })
  return value
})

const getCurrentQuestion = computed(() => {
  let question = questions.value[currentQuestion.value]
  questions.index = question.value
  return question 
})

const setAnswer = evt => {
  questions.value[currentQuestion.value].selected = evt.target.value
  evt.target.value = null
}

const nextQuestion = () => {
  if(currentQuestion.value < questions.value.length -1) {
    currentQuestion.value++
    console.log('currentQuestion.value type:', typeof currentQuestion.value);
console.log('questions.value.length type:', typeof questions.value.length);
console.log(currentQuestion.index, value);

  } else {
    quizCompleted.value = true
    console.log('Quiz Completed')
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <main class="app">
    <h1>The Quiz</h1>

    <section class="quiz">
      <div class="quiz-info">
        <div class="question">{{ getCurrentQuestion.question }}</div>
        <div class="score">Score {{ score }}/{{ questions.length }}</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="options">
        <label v-for="(option, index) in getCurrentQuestion.options" 
          :key="index"
          :class="`option ${
            getCurrentQuestion.selected == index
              ? index == getCurrentQuestion.answer
                ? 'correct'
                : 'wrong'
                : ''
          } ${
            getCurrentQuestion.selected != null &&
            index != getCurrentQuestion.selected
            ? 'disabled'
            : ''
          }`">
          <input 
            type="radio" name="options"
            :name="getCurrentQuestion.index"
            :value="index"
            v-model="getCurrentQuestion.selected"
            :disabled="getCurrentQuestion.selected"
            @change="setAnswer" />
            <div>{{ option }}</div>  
        </label>
      </div>

      <button
        @click="nextQuestion"
        :disabled="!getCurrentQuestion.selected">
        {{ 
          getCurrentQuestion.index == questions.length - 1
            ? 'Finish'
            : getCurrentQuestion.selected == null
              ? 'Select an option'
              : 'Next Question'
         }}
        </button>
    </section>
  </main>

</template>

<style scoped>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #271C36;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>



i tried to console log the nextquestion function to find an issue and couldnt...
also i think the error lies in the button logic button im not sure

I do not know vue. But looking at your code you have to modify the button after the last question is answered. - not when the user clicks the question-button.

well i want the button text to change to finish as soon as the last question loads, than when a person selects a answer the button is enabled.  an the person can submit test.

getCurrentQuestion returns a question, which does not have a index property. Therefore, getCurrentQuestion.index (undefined) will never equal questions.length - 1 (2).
The correct condition would be: currentQuestion === questions.length - 1.

A few side notes:

I would name currentQuestion: currentIndex or currentQuestionIndex
keep clear of loose comparison operators (== and !=)
you don't need setAnswer. Use v-model.number
you don't need the getCurrentQuestion. I'd use:

    <section
      class="quiz"
      v-for="current in [questions[currentQuestion]]"
      :key="current.question"
    >
      <!-- use `current` -->
    </section>

See it working here

ok thank you! that makes sense now that i think back to some of the errors i got when console logging the nextQuestion function.
